# How to use generic params from outer function

Tags: generics, rust, enums, traits

I have a test function with a generic param:

```
fn  my_func()<G: A + B + C>() {
  let my_val = Val::<G>::new(); // Able to do this

  // G must implement A + B + C since I have G already defined in my_func() I wanna use it
  enum MyEnum<G> {
    First(FirstValue<G>), // Requires trait implementation A + B + C
    Second(SecondValue<G>), // Requires trait implementation A + B + C
  }
}
```

But the enum throws a compilation error: `trait bound A must be implemented for FirstValue`

On further investigation I get the compiler error: `can't use generic parameters from outer function use of generic parameter from outer function`.

How can I solve this without redefining G for the enum separately?

Comment: "How can I solve this without redefining G for the enum separately?" you can't, there is no relation whatsoever between the G defined on the function and the G defined on the enum. They're basically different lexical blocks, each with their own independent G. And [they can't be inherited](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error_codes/E0401.html) so you can't remove `G` from `MyEnum` hoping that it'd "close over" the outer `G` either. Also providing an actual MRE would be useful, your snippet is not even syntactically valid.

Comment: The code you gave doesn't throw this error. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).